# How to clean up multiple file names using bash?

Tags: string, bash, date, filenames

I have. directory with ~250 .txt files in it. Each of these files has a title like this:

`Abraham Lincoln [December 01, 1862].txt`

`George Washington [October 25, 1790].txt`

etc...

However, these are terrible file names for reading into python and I want to iterate over all of them to change them to a more suitable format.

I've tried similar things for changing single variables that are shared across many files. But I can't wrap my head around how I should iterate over these files and change the formatting of their names while still keeping the same information.

The ideal output would be something like

`1861_12_01_abraham_lincoln.txt`

`1790_10_25_george_washington.txt`

etc...

Comment: Post your attempts (code) and explain how and why they failed

Comment: "terrible file names for reading into python" - why?

Comment: As Amadan says, there's no reason for Python to have trouble with filenames with spaces and square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the straightforward (tedious) bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A map=(["January"]="01" ["February"]="02" ["March"]="03" ["April"]="04" ["May"]="05" ["June"]="06" ["July"]="07" ["August"]="08" ["September"]="09" ["October"]="10" ["November"]="11" ["December"]="12")

pat='^([^[]+) \[([A-Za-z]+) ([0-9]+), ([0-9]+)]\.txt$'
for i in *.txt; do
    if [[ $i =~ $pat ]]; then
        newname="$(printf "%s_%s_%s_%s.txt" "${BASH_REMATCH[4]}" "${map["${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"]}"  "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}" "$(tr 'A-Z ' 'a-z_' <<< "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")")"
        mv -- "$i" "$newname"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Nice. Didn't know about BASH_REMATCH. Was going to write something using sed.

Comment: You could make this a little more efficient by using `printf -v newname "%s_%s_%s_%s.txt" ...` and thus not needing the command substitution's `fork()`, FIFO creation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in *.txt; do
    # extract parts of the filename to be differently formatted with a regex match
    [[ $file =~ (.*)\[(.*)\] ]] || { echo "invalid file $file"; exit; }

    # format extracted strings and generate the new filename
    formatted_date=$(date -d "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" +"%Y_%m_%d")
    name="${BASH_REMATCH[1]// /_}"  # replace spaces in the name with underscores
    f="${formatted_date}_${name,,}" # convert name to lower-case and append it to date string
    new_filename="${f::-1}.txt"     # remove trailing underscore and add `.txt` extension

    # do what you need here
    echo $new_filename
    # mv $file $new_filename
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to pull the filename apart, then put it back together.

Also GNU date can parse-out the time, which is simpler than using `sed` or a big `case` statement to convert "October" to "10".

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "" ] || [ "$1" == "--help" ]; then
    echo "Give a filename like \"Abraham Lincoln [December 01, 1862].txt\" as an argument"
    exit 2
fi

filename="$1"

# remove the brackets
filename=`echo "$filename" | sed -e 's/[\[]//g;s/\]//g'`

# cut out the name
namepart=`echo "$filename" | awk '{ print $1" "$2 }'`

# cut out the date
datepart=`echo "$filename" | awk '{ print $3" "$4" "$5 }' | sed -e 's/\.txt//'`

# format up the date (relies on GNU date)
datepart=`date --date="$datepart" +"%Y_%m_%d"`

# put it back together with underscores, in lower case
final=`echo "$namepart $datepart.txt" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | sed -e 's/ /_/g'`

echo mv \"$1\" \"$final\"
```

EDIT: converted to BASH, from Bourne shell.

Comment: Note that `=` should be used instead of `==` to be in habits that are compatible with `/bin/sh`. See [the POSIX specification for `test` and `[`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)

Comment: ...it's also strongly recommended to use `$( )` instead of backticks; among other things, backslashes work more consistently inside `$( )`, whereas their behavior inside backticks is different from their behavior outside them (necessarily, because backslashes need to be used to escape inner backticks if you nest command substitutions, whereas `$( )` nests natively). Using `$( )` may not be supported in 1970s Bourne, but on modern systems `/bin/sh` is POSIX sh rather than legacy Bourne; ever since the original publication of POSIX.2 in 1991, `$( )` has been part of the POSIX sh standard.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree with your comments mostly.  But here I'm specifically using bash, and when I do-so, I use ==.   For execution, I prefer to use backticks, as `$()` syntax is used for too much look-alike stuff, I find back-ticks easier to recognise for what it is, whereas `$(something)` requires a more careful read-over.  But, yes sometimes it is a pain in the backslashes.

Comment: The use of `==` can be justified, but backticks really can't.  See [BashFAQ #82](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) for a full discussion -- `$( )` is unambiguously more consistent syntax, and thus easier to read. Also see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst#a_closer_look_at_the_two_forms